# win32 controls (QWinHost) not painted on layered (ie. semi-transparent) widget (WS_EX_LAYERED)

Tags: qt, winapi, qpainter, ws-ex-layered

I ported a win32 control using QWinHost, and put it on a layered (semi-transparent) widget. When I set WS_EX_LAYERED flag, then paint not occurred for win32 ported control.

```
SetWindowLong(winId(),
           GWL_EXSTYLE,
           GetWindowLong(winId(), GWL_EXSTYLE) | *WS_EX_LAYERED*);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, unfortunately your question is not a great fit for the format of the website: it doesn't tell what you have tried so far, what research you have to done, etc.  You should edit your question to make it specific to a particular problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Windows how to paint the layered window.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507#layerwin_topic2a) says that there are two ways; you almost certainly want [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since you don't want to alter the control's painting code.

So after

```
SetWindowLong(winId(),
           GWL_EXSTYLE,
           GetWindowLong(winId(), GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
```

add

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(winId(), RGB(0,0,0), bAlpha, LWA_ALPHA);
```

(Adjusted, of course, for your needs).

Note that the layered window must be a top-level window on Windows 7 below; only Windows 8 and above support layered child windows.